# Backbone does not load

Tags: symfony, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone js and Im having trouble getting the js files to load with the view.

Im using Symfony2 and working on someone elses code.

My html view and backbone files are quite simple.

In my view:

```
<div id="accountManager" class="user-edit-form">
    <div class="user-edit-form">
        <div class="button-set">
        {{ form_widget(form.save, { 'attr': {'class': 'button-primary button-save'} }) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my backbone view:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'spinner'
], function( $, _, Backbone, Spinner) {

    var accountView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#accountManager .user-edit-form',

        events: {
            'click .button-save': 'updateUser'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            console.log("I AM LOADED");
            this.$formHolder = this.$('.user-edit-form');
            this.$loadingHolder = this.$('.user-edit-form .loading-mask');
        },

        render: function () {
            return this;
        },

        updateUser: function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('clicked');
            alert("clicked");
            return false;
        }

    });

    return accountView;

});
```

Assetic is combining all the js files into one when I run the relevant commands, so this code should appear along with any html loaded. Do I need to tell symfony to load this file somewhere or should it be listening for the `#accountManager` element to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the app was using a [router](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/). Hopefully this helps someone in having the same problem in the future.

The code for it looks like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'vm'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Vm) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        instance: null
    });


    var initialize = function ( options ) {

        var appView = options.appView;
        var router = new AppRouter(options);

        if ($('#accountManager').length > 0) {
            require(['views/admin/AccountManager'], function (AccountManagerView) {
                var accountManagerView = Vm.create(appView, 'AccountManagerView', AccountManagerView);
                accountManagerView.render();
            });
        }

        // Lots of other view ifs

        AppRouter.instance = router;

        Backbone.emulateJSON = false;

        Backbone.history.start({
            root: returnRoot(),
            pushState: 'pushState' in window.history
            // the server is handling the initial route and rendering your deep link
        });

    };

    var returnRoot = function () {
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        var pieces = pathname.split('/');
        if (pathname.indexOf('app_dev.php') > -1) {
            return pieces[0];
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        AppRouter: AppRouter
    };

});
```